# How can I schedule a VBA Macro to run once a day at a specific time without opening the excel sheet or the vba macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know where to even begin, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `Task Scheduler` assuming you are in Windows environment. In VBA `Workbook_Open` event. Your chances of getting complete code written by someone else are pretty low.

Comment: Question is too Vague/Broad.  You could use windows scheduler to open the excel document daily and the macro close it.  you could use wsscript to write vbaesque and call it via a windows scheduler.... you could call powershell via windows scheduler.   What you're missing in this is a SCHEDULER.  windows scheduler is just 1 example.   You could write your own service that runs in the background as a scheduler; but why reinvent the wheel.  [task scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Without opening the workbook (you can automate this) it won't work. A VBA code can only interact with an open workbook.

Comment: thank you very much,let me try the solution and see if it will work

Comment: @james Set aside a couple of weeks to get this working if you really are starting out afresh. The terms I use in my answer should at least set you on your way with your Googling.

Comment: and don't forget to handle exceptions.  What happens if the power is off on the computer with the schedule?  what should happen?  What happens if the file is locked when the scheduler runs?  you need to somehow notify if the job is not successful in it's task so that appropriate action can be taken; which is why often a .bat or program to handle such things is called.

Comment: well let me give it a shot but if i was to do it while opening the workbook how will i do it using the ontime function

Comment: @james: The "ontime" timer will be killed off once the process terminates.

Comment: @Bathsheba oh so how can i do it alternatively ??

Comment: I'm not sure you want an alternative to my solution which I've used in production for 10 years (for some market data process where the only API available is Excel functions). Just code it up and enjoy doing so!

Comment: We can't even tell if the VBA macro should be run? Perhaps it does something outside of Excel that could be done another way?

Answer (score 5):

One solution:

1. Configure the Windows Task Scheduler to launch a batch file at a certain time each day.
2. That batch file runs a VBScript file (use cscript or wscript).
3. The VBScript interacts with Excel via Excel's COM interface.

In terms of implementation, do (3) first, then (2), then (1). Of course, this will in a sense "open" the excel sheet concerned, but you can have this whole thing set up as a background process, so you won't notice.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution it worked perfectly

Comment: @james: Congratulations for the implementation. Takes a while, no?

Comment: No it doesn't the solution is quick

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several options, but I would say the #1 choice is Windows task Scheduler.

1. Press the Windows + R keys to open the Run dialog, type taskschd.msc, and press Enter.
   NOTE: This will open Task Scheduler. This file is located at:
   C:\Windows\system32\taskschd.msc.
2. While having Task Scheduler Library selected in the left pane, click/tap on Create task in the far right pane. (see screenshot below)

   Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step1.jpg
3. Under the General tab, type in the "Name" of the program you want to create this shortcut for. (see screenshot below)
   NOTE: This will be the name of the task. As an example, I will use CCleaner for that program. Make note of this name, you will need it later in step 12 and 14 below.

   Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step2.jpg
4. Check the Run with highest privileges box. (See screenshot below)

   Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step3.jpg
5. Click/tap on the Configure for drop down box to open it, and select Windows® 7, Windows Server™ 2008 R2 or the Windows you are currently in. (see screenshot above and below)
   NOTE: This is like compatibility mode. If the program does not support running in Windows 7 normally, then you can select the OS that is does support running in instead to have it run in compatibility mode as if it was running in that OS instead of Windows 7.

   Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-drop_down_box.jpg
6. Click/tap on the Actions tab, then on the New button. (see screenshot below)

   Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step4.jpg
7. In the Program/script: box in the Actions tab, copy and paste the path below. (see screenshot below step 9)
   NOTE: Thank you to chillz for the updated steps 7 and 8.

   %windir%\System32\cmd.exe
8. In the Add arguments (optional): box in the Actions tab, type in the argument below. (see screenshot below step 9)

NOTE: Substitute Task Name in the argument below with the name you entered in step 3 (ex: CCleaner) within quotes, and substitute Full Path of Program in the argument below with the actual full path of the program's .exe file within quote.

```
/c start "Task Name" "Full Path of Program"


For example:

Code:

/c start "CCleaner" "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe"
```

9. Click/tap on OK. (see screenshot below)

   Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step7.jpg
10. Click/tap on the Conditions tab, and uncheck the Stop if the computer switches to battery power box first, then uncheck the Start the task only if the computer is on AC power box. (see screenshots below)
    NOTE: This step is mostly for laptops, so that you will be able to run the program when the laptop is running on battery power.

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step8.jpg

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-conditions.jpg
11. Click/tap on OK. (See screenshots above)
12. You will now see your new task created with the name (ex: CCleaner) you gave it in step 3. Close Task Scheduler. (see screenshot below)

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step9.jpg
13. Right click or press and hold on an empty area of your desktop, then click/tap on New and Shortcut.
14. Type in the target below for the location field, then click/tap on the Next button. (see screenshot below)
    NOTE: Subsitute task-name in the target with the name (ex: CCleaner) within quotes that you used in step 3.

    schtasks /run /tn "task-name"

    For example: For my task name CCleaner I used from step 3, I would type:

    ```
    schtasks /run /tn "CCleaner"
    ```

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step10.jpg
15. Type in a name you want for the shortcut (ex: CCleaner), then click/tap on the Finish button. (see screenshot below)

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step11.jpg
16. Right click on the new shortcut (ex: CCleaner) on the desktop, then click/tap on Properties.
17. Click/tap on the Shortcut tab, and on the Change Icon button. (see screenshot below)

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step12.jpg
18. Click/tap on OK. (see screenshot below)

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step13.jpg
19. Click/tap on the Browse button. (see screenshot below)

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step14.jpg
20. Navigate to the .exe file of the program that you have created this shortcut with, select it, and click/tap on Open. (see screenshot below)
    NOTE: If you have a icon of your own that you would prefer to use instead, then navigate to where you have that icon saved at instead.

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step15.jpg
21. Select the icon you want for the shortcut, then click/tap on OK. (see screenshot below)

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step16.jpg
22. Click/tap on OK. (see screenshot below)

    Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create-step17.jpg
23. You can now use this elevated shortcut to run at startup in your "Startup" folder, run at startup as a task, Pin to Start Menu, Pin to Taskbar, assign a keyboard shortcut, or move to where you like for easy use.
24. When you run this new elevated shortcut, you will now no longer have to click/tap on YES to approve the UAC prompt to allow the program run as administrator.

See the link below for all details.

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

If you are using Windows 8 or newer, see this link.

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

Comment: thank you very much,They had explained that method to me but not in depth,but now you just made it more clearer.